# Subject - Verb Agreement: Repitiendo..., y determinando, ilustra

Tags: verbos, imperativo, concordancia-verbal

Repitiendo este proceso muchas veces, y determinando la proporción de éxitos para cada muestra, **ilustra** la idea de la variabilidad de muestra a muestra en la proporción muestral.

Should **ilustra** or **ilustran** be used? We have *repitiendo* and *determinando...*
in a parenthetical expression but these two can both be the subjects.

Comment: Perhaps "se ilustra". But you repeated "muestra/l" four times, and in Spanish that sounds odd.

Comment: Is this an indication of a problem you must solve? Is this in a book or a test?

Comment: As it stands the expression is incorrect and even difficult to understand. Could you post the original?

Comment: @leonbloy I think the expression is correct if it is an instruction like from a book or so.

Comment: It is from a description of an educational curriculum.

Comment: @aparente note we were discussing about adding concordancia + verbos, didn't we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `ilustra` nor `ilustran` should be used! You can't use them because in fact *repitiendo* and *determinando* cannot be the subject of the sentence. In Spanish, unlike in English, [gerunds cannot act as nouns](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Gerundio), so they cannot be the subject...

The infinitive, however, [can act as a noun](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Infinitivo#Rasgos_comunes_con_los_sustantivos), so you could change the verbs of the sentence to their infinitive form: `repetir` and `determinar`. And in this case, I'd go for `ilustra`, since both `repetir` and `determinar` must be done together as a single process...

Anyway, if you want to keep the gerund forms, you need a subject for your sentence, so you have a couple of options:

- The best option in my opinion would be to use `se ilustra` (*[pasiva refleja](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Pasiva%20refleja%20e%20impersonal%20refleja-NGLE.htm)*).
- But you could also use `ilustramos` or `ilustran`, depending on who is performing the actions, namely who is *repitiendo* and *determinando* (we or they)...

Comment: Thank you. This sentence was taken from a document originally translated from English. Now I am translating it back to English (without having seen the English version) to see if the Spanish translation conveys the same meaning as the English version.

Comment: The actual reason for *ilustra* is that infinitives are of the neuter when nominalized and that only exists in singular. You can see a similar effect in *me gusta....* No matter how many infinitives, no matter how close or distantly related, it will always be *gusta*

Answer (score 1):

If this is part of a problem you must solve, like a practice after learning something, it is Ok.

*Repitiendo este proceso muchas veces, y determinando la proporción de éxitos para cada muestra*, **ilustra** la idea de la variabilidad de muestra a muestra en la proporción muestral.

The first part is telling you what you are going to do, you'll repeat the process you learn (that I asumme is a part of the text you didn't write) and after doing it, it indicates you need to write on your own words "**Ilustrar"**- what variability from sample to sample,in the sample proportion, means.

Why use Ilustra? Why not Ilustrar?. It is because is an instruction so the verb is not longer in its infinitive form:

```
"Write the answer"- "Escribe la respuesta"

"Explain the concept" - "Ilustra el concepto"
```

On a book/test never says *"Ilustrar concepto", "Escribir respuesta"*

---

(Editor's note: in other words, **ilustra** is an **imperative verb**, conjugated in the informal **tú**.)

Comment: I am not asking about the infinitive. I am asking about why not use "ilustran?"

Comment: That's what I tried to explain. It is not ilustran because it is said as an instruction to you, not as a description of something already done. "Con base a lo anterior, (tú) ilustra el concepto"